# Accessing SQLite Database Through Assets

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

Im trying to use ionic with the SQLite plugin (https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin) and I was able to create and use a database, but in my app i need a prepopulated database.

I see methods of achieving this by placing the database in the platforms/android/assets folder in the ionic project, and then copying it, on the first android run, to the "correct location".

My question is, why is it needed to copy it to another location? why cant I just access it from the assets folder which the application creates? If it was an image, i wouldnt need to change its place either, i would use it from the assets, so why not the db too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database file in the assets folder is stored in an exported file format (minimum storage space required, but not for interactive use). The Android SQLite Database needs to import this file. This means reading and storing it in a new format for better searching/reading and writing.

So it is not a simple copying process it's an interaction and after the import your database does not read from your assets folder any longer. So replacing your database in your assets folder does not update your imported database.

You can use this project to import your database in android: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper